# Drupal 7: Sharing authentication with HTTP-Auth

Tags: php, mysql, apache, drupal, drupal-7

I want to do [what is described here](http://drupal.org/node/156547), but with Drupal 7.

Before version 7, passwords were saved in database as a md5 hash, so you could use `Auth_MySQL`.

In this example, I'm trying to allow access on `gitweb` only to valid drupal users:

File: `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/default-ssl`

```
    <Directory /usr/share/gitweb>
            AuthName "site name"
            AuthType Basic

            Auth_MySQL On
            Auth_MySQL_Authoritative on

            Auth_MySQL_Host localhost
            Auth_MySQL_Username drupal_user
            Auth_MySQL_Password drupal_password
            Auth_MySQL_DB drupal_database
            Auth_MySQL_Password_Table users
            Auth_MySQL_Username_Field name
            Auth_MySQL_Password_Field pass
            Auth_MySQL_Encryption_Types PHP_MD5
            Auth_MySQL_Password_Clause " AND status=1"
            Auth_MySQL_Empty_Passwords Off

            AuthBasicAuthoritative Off
            AuthUserFile /dev/null

            require valid-user
    </Directory>
```

Looking into database, with `select name,pass from users;`, passwords hashes are like this: `$S$DSmryVGZQg2AsLOFBT68xoQaEqPA1TWe4gi2gezh93tAjrbskFUi` because they are "salted", not classic md5 hash like in older drupal version?

I know that is possible to check if a password matches the hashed password with the function `user_check_password($password, $account)` [=>api](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!password.inc/function/user_check_password/7).

**How to let Apache using Drupal 7 users/password as authentication system?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I've found the solution: [mod-auth-external](http://code.google.com/p/mod-auth-external/).

Install the module, if it's not yet installed

```
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-authnz-external
sudo a2enmod authnz_external
```

Add this to http.conf

```
DefineExternalAuth drupal environment /var/www/drupal-authentication.php
```

Add this to .htaccess in protected directory:

```
AuthType basic
AuthName "GitWeb"
AuthBasicProvider external
AuthExternal drupal
Require valid-user
```

Edit /var/www/drupal-authentication.php (or where your drupal installation is)

```
#!/usr/bin/php5
<?php

empty($_SERVER['SHELL']) && die('shells only please');

define('DRUPAL_ROOT', '/var/www');
require_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/includes/bootstrap.inc';
drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);

$username = getenv('USER');
$password = getenv('PASS');

$auth = user_authenticate($username, $password);

if (!$auth) {
  exit(1);
}

exit(0);
```

This example is working: when accessing /gitweb directory or any file inside it, browser asks for username and password. The login is successfull only if username and password match drupal's one.

#### Security

I'm not sure how much safe this is. It needs testing.

#### Performance

`drupal-authentication.php` is called for each http request, so performance are low. You can improve efficience with `mod_authz_socache` as described [here](http://code.google.com/p/mod-auth-external/wiki/ConfigApache24#2.1._External_Password_Authenticators)

Comment: I created a new version of this script, using @jam1123's pipe method and also ensuring authentication does not go through unchecked if bootstrapping Drupal fails: https://gist.github.com/anjackson/7664b2acffbcc77a2905

Answer (score 3):

It may be noted that according to the mod-auth-external (or mod-authnz-external) [docs](http://code.google.com/p/mod-auth-external/wiki/ConfigApache22) the default/preferred method of communicating to an authenticator is via the **pipe** method rather than by 'environment'. In the accepted answer, http.conf (or apache2.conf, or the < Directory > of your virtual host) would include the line:

```
DefineExternalAuth drupal pipe /var/www/html/drupal-authentication.php
```

Then /var/www/html/drupal-authentication.php would be changed to:

```
$username = trim(fgets(STDIN));
$password = trim(fgets(STDIN));
```

Finally, if you're getting a REMOTE_ADDR error in your logs from 'bootstrap.inc', you can [change how you load bootstrap](http://drupal.org/node/1009966) to prevent this from firing. In /var/www/html/drupal-authentication.php:

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] = 'www.example.com';
$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] = '127.0.0.1';

define('DRUPAL_ROOT', dirname(realpath(__FILE__)));
require_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/includes/bootstrap.inc';
drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);
```

Comment: This is interesting. I'll try it. Thank you :)